# How to hide InfluxDB measurement Tags in a Grafana Panel

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb, flux, telegraf

I have a Grafana dashboard reading data from an InfluxDB OSS 2.7 instance. I am using the [Telegraf Docker input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/release-1.26/plugins/inputs/docker) to measure the memory usage of a number of docker containers.

When writing my query, I get the measurement I want (container memory usage), but it comes with a lot of non-human-readable tags (compose-hash, etc.). The non-human-readable info makes the visualization very hard to read.

[image: Lots of tags]

All I want is to display the docker container name, and the memory usage. None of the tags are important.

I don't want to prevent that information from being sent by telegraf or stored in the InfluxDB, it may be useful for debugging later. I just don't want to display it.

Here is the Flux query I am using:

```
fields = ["usage", ]
from(bucket: "MyBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r.host == "${Host}" and
    r._measurement == "docker_container_mem" and
    contains(value: r.container_name, set:[${Containers:csv}]) and
    contains(value: r._field, set:fields)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding a `group()` and `aggregateWindow()` function to the end of my query.

```
fields = ["usage", ]
from(bucket: "MyBucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop:v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r.host == "${Host}" and
    r._measurement == "docker_container_mem" and
    contains(value: r.container_name, set:[${Containers:csv}]) and
    contains(value: r._field, set:fields)
  )
  |> group(columns: ["_field", "container_name", "host"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
```

I have no idea why the `aggregateWindow()` is required, but the data doesn't display graph without it.